# WSL2 + Ubuntu20.04LTS - localhost not emitting to parent

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I'm trying to develop inside WSL. So I installed **Ubuntu20.04LTS** and **Ubuntu18.04LTS** both. Also installed all the necessary deps and files. Then I started facing this problem: **`Error: read ECONNRESET`**

In the root directory(`C:/Users/MUA`) of the parent system, where wsl is installed, I've added `.wslconfig` file  containing:

```
[wsl2]
localhostForwarding=true
```

Inside `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\etc`, the file `hosts` got reflected. Now it looks something like this:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   MUA.localdomain MUA

192.168.0.101   host.docker.internal
192.168.0.101   gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1   kubernetes.docker.internal

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

But still, I can't access these ports. Tried all the proposed solutions like:

- disable fast boot
- upgrading to wsl2

***Can anyone give me a solution?***

Answer (score 0):

**I'm quite sure that, this is not the solution, so I'm not accepting it as an answer.**

I've found some workaround like:

- Downgrade to `WSL1` for `Ubuntu 20.04LTS`
- Install another instance of `Ubuntu 18.04LTS` with `WSL2`
- Running docker and other required applications in the `WSL2`
- `WSL1` comes with all the networking support, no need to configure